# Python issue with "input"

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the user input a one-word answer and then, later on, the answer which they inputted will be printed inside the new question. 
This is my code:

```
device= input ("what device do you have?")

if (device== "phone"):

    print(" ")

elif (device== "samsung"):

  pass

Power = input ("what 'power' make do you have?")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What about 2017? how's that relevant to the question?

Comment: `Power = input ("what " + device + " make do you have? ")` Is this what you are asking?

Comment: This is totally  irrelevant question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
answer1 = input("what device do you have? ")
answer2 = input("looks like you are using '{0}' as a device, but why? ".format(answer1))

print(answer2)
```